# Edittext InputFilter and autosuggestions

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext, filtering, autosuggest

By example, i have an input filter, which block any characters in edititext:

```
 editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            return "";
        }
    }});
```

But autosuggestions continue updating, so user can click on thems or press back button and edittext will be filled with filtered data. 
Hоw to avoid this strange logic? (Do not change autosuggestions, when characher was filtered) Tested on huawei ascend p6.

Comment: Did you try adding `android:inputType="textFilter"` or `"textNoSuggestions"` to your EditText?

Comment: @smarroufin i tried that, so that inputTypes just blocks autocomplete, but i need it. An autocomplete should work, when characters pass my filter. I provide an evertything blocking filter only to describe an issue better.